# 301 redirect all subpages to the frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

We are closing down a site, so we need to 301 redirect all the subpages on the site to the frontpage (where we will have a message about the site closing down, etc.)

But how do we do that using .htaccess?

Currently our .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't 301 redirect the subpages to the frontpage (and we would like to keep the non-www to www redirection).

Thanks,
Louisa

Comment: That code is designed to redirect non www domains to www domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"^/$"
RewriteRule (.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```